# during git rebase: same file keeps conflicting

Tags: git, git-rebase

I checked out a branch called 'topic'. I am still working on topic, but I want to include changes that are now in master branch. So I did this:

```
$ git checkout topic
$ git rebase master
```

After that, there were merge conflicts for file `xyz.txt`. So I modified file to be what I wanted, git add it, and did `git rebase --continue`.

But immediatly, the same file had merge conflicts. I fixed the file again and this time had to do `git reabase --skip` to continue.

**But *yet again* the same file has the exact same merge conflicts. How is this happening?**

EDIT:

Previously, I had been merging master into topic branch to accomplish this purpose. Then I just learned of rebase. So I'm guessing that has something to do with it.

---

Here is the state of git right now right before the third commit

```
$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#       both modified:      xyz.java
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git ls-files -u
100644 cbf74a88604dd4ee0afe89d7aac1d179ce75e92c 1       xyz.java
100644 52841c2b4b6cc055251d533d5b83441d1329b412 2       xyz.java
100644 c45e7c6b979ec1e20b7dd70b38698193ea235abd 3       xyz.java

$ git log --graph --pretty=format:%d HEAD master topic
*  (HEAD)
*
*  (master)
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
| *  (topic)
| *
| |\
| |/
|/|
* |
| *
| *
| |\
| |/
|/|
* |
| *
| *
| *
| *
| *
| |\
| |/
|/|
* |
| *
| *
| *
| *
| *
| *
| *
| |\
| |/
|/|
* |
* |
* |
|\ \
| * |
* | |
|/ /
| *
| *
| |\
| |/
|/|
* |
| *
| *
| *
| *
| *
| *
| *
| *
| *
| |\
| |/
|/|
* |
| *
| |\
| |/
|/|
* |
| *
| *
| *
| *
|/
*
*
```

Comment: Just to check, since you don't state it explicitly, when you get the conflict and edit your file, do you then do a `git add <file>; git commit` before you do the `git rebase --continue`?

Comment: yes. I git add it. I updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `git rebase --interactive` to validate how Git will rebase the history. There will be a list of commits that will be applied in the given order ontop of your base commit, i.e. `master`:

Example:

```
pick 12345678 # This will be the first commit of your rebased topic branch
pick deadbeef
pick ffffffff
pick 01010101 # This will be HEAD after the successful rebase
```

Sometimes, Git doesn't know if a commit is really new in a branch or just an existing commit (from `master`) with different ancestors. You can skip commits by removing them from the text file.

If this doesn't solve your conflicts immediately, there's a *real* conflict between the two branches. Be sure to merge the file(s) and stage them using `git add`. Afterwards be sure to use `git rebase --continue` to move on. Don't use `git rebase --skip` if you don't know exactly that it's useful here. (`--skip` will ignore the current, conflicting commit and try to apply the next commit, which might result in further inscrutable conflicts later on).

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know how this causes the issue, but I am very sure that the problem arises from the fact that I previously was merging instead of rebasing. But I haven't pushed `topic` yet, so I will just go through the whole rebase process.

Comment: Please, do not answer your own question if it's not really an answer. Instead, edit your question to provide additional information.

Comment: I see your point. I posted this because I'm positive that having previously merged the branches _is_ the cause of this issue. So I feel this answer is accurate in it's answer to the question, but lacks sufficient precision because I don't know _why_ this is the answer. At least, so was my thinking.